# RxJS keeping a source Observable alive if a switchMapped Observable emits an error

Tags: javascript, rxjs, switchmap

In the following example, the `interval` Observable will stop emitting values after the first `throwError` emits.

```
const { interval, throwError, of } = Rx;
const { take, switchMap, catchError } = RxOperators;

interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => throwError('error')),
  catchError(() => of(null)),
  take(4)
)
```

However in the following example, the `interval` Observable will stay alive and emit 4 times on to the `throwError` Observable.

```
const { interval, throwError, of } = Rx;
const { take, switchMap, catchError } = RxOperators;

interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => throwError('error').pipe(catchError(() => of(null)))),
  take(4)
)
```

I have a situation where I need the behaviour in the second example where the main Observable stays alive even if the Observable that is switchMapped on to emits an error.

My understanding is that embedding pipes within pipes is bad practice due to the complexity it can add to understanding what the code is doing. Is there a nicer way to achieve the behaviour from the second example?

Comment: You have the right idea. Some complexity is inherent to the problem. Often you can extract some of the logic into a custom operator or a separate function if it's looking too cluttered.